# What is meant by "observation covariance"?

Tags: simulation, terminology, gaussian-process

I am reading Williams et al. 2006, Combining Experimental Data and Computer Simulations, from the journal Bayesian Analysis [(link)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1340370942). It provides a framework for combining $n$ points of field data $y$ with $m$ points of simulation output $\eta$, using a Gaussian process emulator. Define $\mathcal D = (y\  \eta)^T$. On page 771 the authors define (begin quote):
$$ \Sigma_{\mathcal D} = \Sigma_\eta + \left( \begin{matrix} \Sigma_y+\Sigma_\delta&0\\0&0\end{matrix} \right)$$
**where $\Sigma_y$ is the $n\times n$ observation covariance matrix**, elements of $\Sigma_\eta$ are obtained by applying [the relevant gaussian process covariance function] to each pair of the $n+m$ simulation input points corresponding to $\mathcal D$... (end quote, bold added).

I suspect it should be obvious what they mean by "the $n\times n$ observation covariance matrix", but it isn't, to me. Is this simply the sample covariance matrix of the observations?